# AssertionError at /api/ Expected a `date`, but got a `datetime`. Refusing to coerce, as this may mean losing timezone information

Tags: django, django-registration

I am creating an API and have some problems:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='')
    description= models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    end_date   = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    reg_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    reg_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    input_date     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author   = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  related_name='yoga_tours')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='input_date')
    status =  models.IntegerField(choices=statuses,default=1)
    objects = models.Manager()  # default manager
    tourobjects = TourObjects()  # custom manager
```

serializers.py

```
class YogatourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'reg_start_date','reg_end_date','author','status')
        model = Yogatour
```

I want to have date field only, without time properties .when I post something, I am getting next error:

```
AssertionError at /api/
Expected a `date`, but got a `datetime`. Refusing to coerce, as this may mean losing timezone information. Use a custom read-only field and deal with timezone issues explicitly.
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the POST you tried?

Comment: @hldev creating object from admin panel

Comment: Can you show the POST body? You can access that in devtools. Probably your frontend is sending date + time fields to your backend.